# Awk file script to parsing 2 different input formats (one per time)

Tags: regex, file, input, awk

I tried to prepare one common awk script file to parse an input file.
The input file has 2 different formats. (input1.txt & input2.txt). It will be one of them (not both on the same file).

awk -f script.awk input1.txt
or
awk -f script.awk input2.txt

I got errors.
Currently I have 2 scripts , but i should check the input file , then apply the specific awk script based on the input format.

Is it possible to correct the script to parse the input file , regardless of the input file format ?

Thanks in advance.

the code is as shown in the:

```
{/^PT             DAIM     SPSE/ {
    printing = 1
    next
}

/^END/ {
    printing = 0
}

/^PT             GSS  CAT/ {
    typing = 1
    next
}

/^END/ {
    typing = 0
}

printing == 1{

/^[0-9]/  { array[1]=trim_blank(substr($0,1,7))   
            array[2]=trim_blank(substr($0,16,7))   
            array[3]=trim_blank(substr($0,25,10)) 
            array[4]=trim_blank(substr($0,37,6))  
            array[5]=trim_blank(substr($0,54,10)) 
            print_array1(array)
}
/NSS / {    getline
            while(NF>1)
            {
               array[6]=trim_blank(substr($0,25,4)) #SSN
               array[7]=trim_blank(substr($0,37,10))#SUBSYSTEMSTATE
               array[8]=trim_blank(substr($0,54,3)) #SST
               print_array2(array)
               getline
            }
       }
}  
  
    } 


typing == 1{
  
    print (" This printout is for C7NCP with SPCHAR ")
    
    } 

function print_array1(array)
{
    printf("%-9s", array[1])
    printf("%-9s", array[2])
    printf("%-11s",array[3])
    printf("%-8s", array[4])
    printf("%-11s",array[5])
    printf("\n");
    for(item=3;item<=5;item++){array[item]=""}
}

function print_array2(array)
{
    printf("%-9s", array[1])
    printf("%-9s", array[2])
    printf("%33s ", array[6])
    printf("%-11s", array[7])
    printf("%-4s", array[8])
    printf("\n");
    for(item=6;item<=8;item++){array[item]=""}
}
function trim_blank(str){
#trim will remove the SPACE & TAB at begining or end of str
  blk=" "
  tab="\t"
  while(1){
    if((substr(str,1,1)==blk)||(substr(str,1,1)==tab)) {str=substr(str,2,(length(str)-1))}
    else if((substr(str,length(str),1)==blk)||(substr(str,length(str),1)==tab)) {str=substr(str,1,(length(str)-1))}
    else {return str}
    }
```

The input files can be one of the following formats:

input1.txt

```
PT             DAIM     SPSE        STATE            PSTATE
2-232          601GSU9  ALLOWED     CON              ALLOWED

                        NSS         PTTT             TTS
                        100         ALLOW            YES
                        100         ALLOW            NO
                        233         ALLOW            YES
                        233         ALLOW            YES
END
```

The 2nd input file format

input2.txt:

```
PT             GSS  CAT  LOP
6-2012         1    0    NO
6-5010         0    1    YES
6-6018         0    1    YES
6-6019         1    0    NO
END
```

The output for the input1.txt should be as

```
PT     DAIM     SPSE     STATE   PSTATE     NSS   PTTT   TTS
2-232  601GSU9  ALLOWED  CON     ALLOWED    100   ALLOW  YES
2-232  601GSU9  ALLOWED  CON     ALLOWED    100   ALLOW  NO
2-232  601GSU9  ALLOWED  CON     ALLOWED    233   ALLOW  YES
2-232  601GSU9  ALLOWED  CON     ALLOWED    233   ALLOW  YES
```

The output for the input2.txt should be as

```
This printout is for C7NCP with SPCHAR 
This printout is for C7NCP with SPCHAR 
This printout is for C7NCP with SPCHAR 
This printout is for C7NCP with SPCHAR
```

The error shown during execution is as shown (when apply with the input1.txt) :-

```
awk: common_parse.awk:2: {/^PT             DAIM     SPSE/ {
awk: common_parse.awk:2:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: common_parse.awk:7: /^END/ {
awk: common_parse.awk:7:        ^ syntax error
awk: common_parse.awk:11: /^PT             GSS  CAT/ {
awk: common_parse.awk:11:                            ^ syntax error
awk: common_parse.awk:16: /^END/ {
awk: common_parse.awk:16:        ^ syntax error
awk: common_parse.awk:20: printing == 1{
awk: common_parse.awk:20:              ^ syntax error
awk: common_parse.awk:22: /^[0-9]/  { array[1]=trim_blank(substr($0,1,7))   
awk: common_parse.awk:22:           ^ syntax error
awk: common_parse.awk:29: /NSS / {    getline
awk: common_parse.awk:29:        ^ syntax error
awk: common_parse.awk:79:
```

Comment: Please, at least fix the obvious errors like the first code block with 2 `{`s but only 1 `}` or the fifth one `printing == 1{`.

Comment: *`I got errors.`* ... and those errors were ... ? please update the question with the error(s) you're receiving;  as already mentioned it looks like you've got some issues with mismatched `{` / `}` pairs; also, you have conditions of `/^END/` and `/SSN/` but these do not show up in any of the sample data ... either *a)* remove unnecessary code or *b)* update the question to show some sample data that would allow these conditions to evaulate to true

Comment: do all of your file consist of a single 6-/8- line block of data? or can these blocks of data repeat, and if they can repeat, what separates each block?

Comment: general design idea: if the line contains `PT / DAIM / SPSE` then set `format_style=1` else if line contains `PT / GSS / CAT` then set `format_style=2`; then have 2 main condition/action pairs: `format_style==1 { ...}` and `format_style==2 { ... }`; there are some variations on this approach but the general idea is to set a flag/variable based on the format of the `^PT ...` line and then incorporate that flag/variable in follow-on conditionals

Comment: the conditional `/^[0-9]/` appears to match (differently formatted) lines in both files; how were you planning to match this conditional against the two differently formatted lines?

Comment: The brace before `/^PT` and after the lone `printing == 1` are clearly syntax errors, just like it tells you. The other problems are fallout from the parser falling over its own feet because of that first error. But if you are completely unfamiliar with Awk syntax, why are you asking us instead of the person who gave you this code?

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 == "END" {
    exit
}
inFmt == 0 {
    inFmt = ( $2 == "DAIM"  ? 1 : 2 )
}
inFmt == 1 {
    if ( NR < 3 ) {
        hdr[NR] = sprintf("%-9s %-9s %-11s %-8s %-11s", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
    }
    else if ( NF ) {
        printf "%s %-6s %-9s %-3s\n", hdr[(NR == 4 ? 1 : 2)], $1, $2, $3
    }
}
inFmt == 2 {
    if ( NR > 1 ) {
        printf "This printout is for C7NCP with SPCHAR\n"
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input1.txt
PT        DAIM      SPSE        STATE    PSTATE      NSS    PTTT      TTS
2-232     601GSU9   ALLOWED     CON      ALLOWED     100    ALLOW     YES
2-232     601GSU9   ALLOWED     CON      ALLOWED     100    ALLOW     NO
2-232     601GSU9   ALLOWED     CON      ALLOWED     233    ALLOW     YES
2-232     601GSU9   ALLOWED     CON      ALLOWED     233    ALLOW     YES
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk input2.txt
This printout is for C7NCP with SPCHAR
This printout is for C7NCP with SPCHAR
This printout is for C7NCP with SPCHAR
This printout is for C7NCP with SPCHAR
```

A few things to mention:

- `getline` is only appropriate to use in a few specific cases and when called in specific ways, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.
- Your `trim_blank()` function implementation is extremely inefficient, it should just be `function trim_blank(str) { gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$/,"",str); return str }`
- When using `printf` to define output format, don't do `printf "%4s%5s\n"` with the areas butting up against each other as then if any string is longer than the specific length the 2 will get concatenated. Always leave a space in between to eliminate that possibility, `printf "%4s %5s\n"`